# How can I throw an exception in Matlab?

Tags: exception, matlab

I am writing some code and for now I am making some functions, but I'm not writing them yet. I'm just making an empty function that will do nothing yet. What I would like to do is throw an exception if the function is run, to prevent me from forgetting writing the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is:

```
error('Some useful error message.')
```

Matlab is happier is you assign an identifer to you error message, like this:

```
error('toolsetname:other_identifying_information','Some useful error message here.')
```

The identifying information is reported with some of the error handling routines, for example, try running `lasterror` after each of the above calls.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use:

```
  throw(MException('Id:id','message'));
```

There is a nice feature to `MException`, it can be used as `sprintf`:

```
  throw(MException('Foo:FatalError',...
  'First argument of Foo is %s, but it must be double',class(varargin{1}) ));
```

As commented correctly by @edric, this `sprintf` functionality can be a double edged sword. If you use some of the escape characters, it might behave not like you want it.

```
throw(MException('Foo:FatalError',...
  'I just want to add a \t, no tab!' ));
```

Comment: Please remember that the 2nd argument to the MException constructor is a *format specifier*, not a string literal. (I've got that wrong in the past, as have many others).

Comment: @Edric, did you mean the sprintf functionality?

Comment: Yes, that's right - I've seen problems where people do stuff like "MException( 'some:id', ['Problem in: ' fname] )" and fname contains "\t" (or worse...) - which then gets turned into a tab character.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the [MATLAB documentation for "Throwing an exception"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/throw-an-exception.html)?

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: The web page is not super clear. It would be awesome if you'd add a sample code in your answer.

Comment: To be fair, the simplest way is to use `error()` as suggested by @Pursuit.